# TypoScript / Typo3: How to build sub-content of a page using header_link value?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

How can I build a **sub-content** (*nested content*) of a page using *typoscript* with reference to the parent's `header_link` field?

Desired output is something like:

```
<h1>Title of parent</h1>
<p class="prt">Body of parent</p>
<h3>Title of Child</h3>
<p class="cld">Contents of child</p>
```

Sample of my Typoscript:

```
temp.myParentVal = CONTENT
temp.myParentVal {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    begin = 1
    orderBy = sorting
    where = (colPos = 1)
  }
  renderObj = COA 
  renderObj {

  10 = TEXT  
  10 {
    required = 1
    wrap = <h1> | </h1>
    stdWrap.field = header
  }
  20 = TEXT  
  20 {
    required = 1
    wrap = <p class="prt"> | </p>
    stdWrap.field = bodytext
  }


  #                                                                #
  #  WHAT SHOULD I DO HERE TO SHOW THE CHILD CONTENT OF THIS PAGE  #
  #  (REFERENCED BY header_link FIELD IN THE PARENT'S ROW),        #
  #  WHICH HAS THE FORMAT OF <child_pid#child_uid>, EG.'11#28'     #
  #                                                                #


  stdWrap.wrap = <div> | </div>
}
```

I would like to make use of parent's header_link field value to generate the content for the child. (I'm using TYPO3 v. 6.2.14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a nested `CONTENT` element and split the `header_link` via Regex like this:

```
30 = CONTENT
30 {
  table = tt_content
  select {
    uidInList {
      field = header_link
      stdWrap.replacement.10 {
        search = /^.+#/
        replace = 
        useRegExp = 1
      }
    }
    pidInList {
      field = header_link
      stdWrap.replacement.10 {
        search = /#.+$/
        replace = 
        useRegExp = 1
      }
    }
  }
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    10 = TEXT  
    10.value {
      required = 1
      wrap = <h3> | </h3>
      field = header
    }
    20 = TEXT  
    20.value {
      required = 1
      wrap = <p class="cld"> | </p>
      field = bodytext
    }
  }
}
```

Also, I wanted to suggest that you use the `field` property directly on the `TEXT` elements (which works). But I looked it up in the docs:

> stdWrap properties are available on the very rootlevel of the object. This is non-standard! You should use these stdWrap properties consistently to those of the other cObjects by accessing them through the property "stdWrap".

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Text/Index.html

As `value` is a `stdWrap` object, you could use it as I did above.